# releasing UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit, uiwindow

I am using 3 UIViewControllers in my app and now I am wondering if it is a good idea to release them when I switch from to another. Obviously, it would be the hidden ones which I really dont need them while they are not visible...
to switch views, I'm using something like this (uiwindow):

```
//this is in the first UIViewController
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:secondController.view];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
//here I release the view controller
[self release];
```

So my question...it's that really worth it? what could be the performance issues?

Also, I would like to ask if someone knows why these lines work in this order (see below). I tried the other way around and I have problems with the orientation which stopped to work? any hints?

```
//working
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:secondController.view];
[self.view removeFromSuperview];

//not working
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:secondController.view];
```

Thanks

Raul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... it's that really worth it? what could be the performance issues?

You can very well release a view controller once you added it as subview of another view(a superView), in which case the superView retains the subview. *[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]* is the superView of *secondController.view* and it retains *secondController.view*. So, that is a correct way to do it and it won't cause any performance issues.

Comment: yeah..I got it..thanks @EmptyStack ;)..also, I just read that removeFromSuperView does release the object (View)..therefore the release call I was talking about it won't be need...now what if I create a uiviewcontroller using retain?..let's say `UIVIewController *uCtrl = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] retain]`...following Apple guidelines I should release the object...isn't it?

Comment: I just realized that removeFromSuperView releases a UIView not a UIViewController...I checked Apple docs and they said that if you retain the view..you have to call release..